# Bone not moving in standalone player

Tags: python, game-engine

I have coded a Blender animation's bones to move while the BGE is running. I made an *Always* sensor run code in a module that changes the bones using `rotation_euler`.

It works fine in the embedded player (the bones change xyz positions as instructed), but not in the standalone player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is actually quite simple:

You cannot have any **errors in your python** scripts/modules, else the Standalone players animation will not run, it just sits there, making you feel sad inside.